# Redgate SQL Compare is not connecting to the target server, though SQL Server Management Studio connects

Tags: sql-server, redgate

I'm using Redgate SQL Compare to compare my databases.

I can connect to my server's database using my local SSMS. I can also test it successfully using `connection.udl` file.

However, even when I use SSMS plugin to compare a local database with a server database, redgate's SQL Compare complains that:

> A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: TCP Provider, error: 0 - Access is denied.)

What might be wrong?

Comment: Hi - I'm a developer for Redgate SQL Compare and I'm sorry to hear that you are having trouble with the product.

Would you be able to provide exact details of which plugin from Redgate you are using including the version number? Are you able to show details of how you have configured the plugin to connect to your local database as well as how SSMS's connect dialog looks for the same database?

Comment: _Access is denied_ sounds like an Anti-virus/Windows Firewall issue.